# Minimal model program for toroidal pairs

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties, minimal-model-program

Suppose $(X, \Delta)$ be a toroidal pair over $Z$ where $f:(X, \Delta) \rightarrow (Z, \Delta_Z)$ is a toroidal morphism (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9707012.pdf sections 1.2, 1.3 for the terminology). Suppose $(X, \Delta) \dashrightarrow (X', \Delta')$ is a step of a minimal model program over $Z$ with respect to $K_X+\Delta$. Let $f':(X', \Delta') \rightarrow (Z, \Delta_Z)$ be the induced morphism. Is $f'$ still toroidal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With $Z$ a point and empty $\Delta$, this would mean that $X’$ is smooth if $X$ is, no?

Comment: I am not sure if a divisorial contraction or flip from a smooth toric variety is again smooth.

Comment: Yes, that was my point. (Except that I don't know why you wrote "toric" above)

Comment: If you allow toroidal, of course target need not be smooth. I don't see what the contradiction is if the target is toroidal. Unless the MMP ends up creating singularities which are even worse than toroidal.

Comment: The toric MMP exists and stays in the toric world...  (I think Matsuki's book has a description).  But I don't see how this helps (ie, if you start with something locally toric, I'm not sure how to guarantee it stays that way, you might contract something that breaks things).

Comment: My understanding is that for a toric variety $X$ with boundary $\Delta$, the pair $(X, \Delta)$ is toroidal, while $(X, \emptyset)$ is toroidal only if $X$ is smooth.